# request.body not giving the desired json in django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have started exploring API stuffs in Django
I want some JsonResponse in Django but I am not getting it

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

# Create your views here.

def api_home(request, *args, **kwargs):
    body = request.body
    print(body)
    data = {}
    try:
        data = json.loads(body)
    except:
        pass
    # print(data)
    data['headers'] = dict(request.headers)
    data['content_type'] = request.content_type
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**Output in terminal**

```
b''
```

**expected OUTPUT**

```
b'{"query":"Hello World!"}'
```

**Python file**

```
import requests

endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"

get_response = requests.get(endpoint, json={"query":"Hello World!"})

print(get_response.json())
```

**Output of this file**

```
{'headers': {'Content-Length': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Host': 
'127.0.0.1:8000', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.27.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, 
deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'content_type': 'text/plain'}
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
{'query':'Hello World!','headers': {'Content-Length': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
'Host':'127.0.0.1:8000', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.27.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 
'gzip,deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'content_type': 
'text/plain'}
```

I am not getting why I am getting different output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link entered was missing a '/' at end
`endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/"`

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?